# Apache Camel HTTP4 and (JSESSIONID) cookies

Tags: cookies, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, jsessionid

I have a relatively complex route that calls 5 different URLs on the same host. The host will occasionally send cookies which I have to return on subsequent calls, like a browser would. I am using Camel 2.10 (no chance of upgrade due to compatibility issues) and this version doesn't seem to configure a cookie store by default. If I would wire in a `BasicCookieStore`, it stands to reason it would be shared by all calls made by HTTP4 component... but this, of course, makes no sense in the context of a web-app shared by many users, so it might be a wrong assumption.

I've also noticed that if I make multiple requests to the same URL, the server should always send a Set-Cookie for JSESSIONID (unless, of course, I (the client) had already sent this cookie), but even though I specifically remove all headers before making the request, the server sends JSESSIONID only the first time. I have tried both with `bridgeEndpoint=true` and without, with no difference in behavior. When accessed using a browser, it behaves as expected.

It seems I'm terribly misunderstanding something about how Camel deals with cookies. Can someone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup the bridgeEndpoint option to be true, camel just setup the http client default cookieStore to be false, which means it doesn't remember any cookies.

If the bridgeEndpoint option is false (the default value), http client use the BasicCookieStore to store cookies.

Comment: Does that mean the cookie would be shared between all routes and all users as there is only one HTTP4 component registered?

Comment: The cookie can be shared within the http client, and the http client is created per endpoint.

Comment: Ok, so all callers of the endpoint would end sharing the cookie. Hmm... I'm guessing I'd need to implement my own CookieStore if I wanted to group cookies per user session id or something like that. I obviously don't want users getting their jsessionids replaced by other people's values.

Comment: camel-http4 supports to setup the custom cookie store. It should be easy for you to replace the default implementation.